# Initializing a global variable with function return value

Tags: swift, initialization, global-variables

I want to use 2 constant and they should be initialized from a function's return value.I want to use these two constants in the same file and 
also the function and constants are in a same file.

```
class myclass{

 static var ip :String
 static var host :String

 init(ip :String, host :String) {
     let  myconstant = self.setEnvVariables()

        let ip = myconstant.0
        let host = myconstant.1
}  


internal func setVariables() -> (String , String){
    let ip,host: String

    if (some condition) != nil){
      ip = "127.0.0.1"
       host = "http://youraddress.com"
    }
    else{
      ip = "10.12"
        host = "http://myaddress.com"
    }
    return (ip,host)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get what you want, but try this:

```
class MyClass {

    static var ip: String!
    static var host: String!

    init() {
        let (ip, host) = MyClass.setVariables()

        MyClass.ip = ip
        MyClass.host = host
    }

    private static func setVariables() -> (String , String) {
         ...
    }
}
```

All Swift global variables/properties must be properly *initialized*. This implies that:

- a *default value* must be assigned to it when declared;
- or it's declared an *optional*, using `nil` as its initial value (e.g., `String!` above).

Or, if don't like using optionals when you don't need to (I don't!), you could use constant properties instead:

```
class MyClass {

    private static let ipHost = MyClass.setVariables()

    static let ip = ipHost.0
    static let host = ipHost.1
}
```

This second option also improves your code design since you are no longer initializing *global variables* inside an *instance initializer*, which generally isn't the right approach.

Comment: The First implementation  works!  also I have tried the second approach                                 class MyClass {

    private static let ipHost = setVariables()

    static let ip = ipHost.0
    static let host = ipHost.1
}       But it is giving error 
 Cannot use instance member 'setEnvVariables' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: @KIFtest You are right! I thought that function was global :-( You need to declare it `static` and call it using your class name as a prefix. I updated my answer; please try again ;)